# How to Group Array here?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two tables like labels and content.I have written inner join for that two table.

i have wirtten code like this..

```
$menu_array=array();
foreach($this->getArticlesByLabels as $k){
  $menu_array[$k['label_name']][]=$k;
}
```

It's showiing

```
Array
(
   [DON'T MISS] => Array
   (
      [0] => Array
      (
         [ID] => 108347
         [Category_id] => 11204
         [title] => Ram Charan\'s GAV movie: Live updates from movie hall
         [text_data] => afadsfas           
      )
```

Here It's showing data with label name.I mean it's grouped by label name but I want to display the data dynamically how to display data using loops..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($this->getArticlesByLabels as $k){
  echo $k['ID'];
  echo $k['Category_id'];
  echo $k['title'];
  echo $k['text_data'];
}
```

Comment: no not like that i want display first label name and after i have to display that label relevant data like that i have to display 3 labels

Answer (score 0):

maybe :

```
$menu_array=array();
foreach($this->getArticlesByLabels as $k){
  $menu_array['label_name']= $k['label_name'];
}
```

or :

```
foreach($this->getArticlesByLabels as $k){
  $menu_array=array($k);
}
```

or for label names :

```
foreach($this->getArticlesByLabels as $k){
  $menu_array=array($k['label_name']);
}
```